# On a density property of signed singular measures

Tags: measure-theory, harmonic-analysis

Suppose that $\mu$ is a signed finite Borel measure which is singular with respect to the Lebesgue measure in $[0,1]$. Is it true that there always exist a point $x\in [0,1]$ such that
\begin{equation*}
 \lim_{\delta \to 0^+} \frac{\mu([x-\delta,x+\delta])}{\delta } = + \infty \quad \text{or} \quad -\infty \quad ?
\end{equation*}

In the case that $\mu$ is positive then it is known (See Rudin "Real and Complex Analysis" Theorem 8.9) that for $\mu - a.e. x$ the above limit is equal to $+\infty$.

Comment: Which edition of Rudin's book are you referring to? There is no Theorem 8.9 in the 3rd edition.

Comment: `signed finite Borel probability measure' is contradictory. You mean signed measure?

Comment: @Christophe Leuridan : corrected thanks

Comment: @IosifPinelis I have the "Real and complex analysis, International student edition, 1970"

Comment: @ChristianRemling But is it clear that $ \{ D\mu_+ = \infty \}$ is disjoint from $ \{  D\mu_- = \infty \} $ ?

Comment: @an_ordinary_mathematician: No, they are indeed not disjoint in general. My original attempt was clumsy, but now the argument should be fine (see below).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this works. Write $d\mu = s\, d|\mu|$, with $|\mu|$ denoting the total variation of $\mu$ and $s(x)=\pm 1$. We can recover $s(x)$ for $|\mu|$-a.e. $x$ as the derivative $s(x)=\lim_{|I|\to 0} \mu(I)/|\mu|(I)$. (Here and below, I write $I$ to denote an interval centered at $x$.)

Since a positive singular measure $\nu$ is supported by the set $\{ \nu(I)/|I| \to\infty\}$, we have $|I|/|\mu|(I)\to 0$ for $|\mu|$-a.e. $x$. Thus if we had $\liminf \mu(I)/|I|<\infty$ for all $x$, then $s(x)$ can never be $1$, so $\mu$ has no positive part.

(The argument in fact shows that $\mu(I)/|I|\to\infty$ almost everywhere with respect to $\mu_+$, the positive part of $\mu$.)

Comment: Very slick argument !